# Is it right that: $z^{\frac12}=[\frac12(r+x)]^{\frac12}\pm i[\frac12(r-x)]^{\frac12}$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

All is in the subject, my professor tel me that it is false , but i find it here: http://people.math.sfu.ca/~cbm/aands/page_17.htm

Thank you

Comment: What are the conditions on $z$, $r$ and $x$? What is the context?

Comment: It would be true if you replaced the last $z$ by $x$ and explained about the $\pm$. To see it you just put $x=r\cos\theta$ and use the half-angle formulae.

Comment: If $r = (x^2 + y^2)^{1/2}$, then we have $$ \sqrt{z} = \sqrt{\tfrac{1}{2}(r+x)} + i \operatorname{sign}(y) \sqrt{\tfrac{1}{2}(r-x)}. $$ So I would say you are correct.

Comment: I have fixed the $z$ in the title.

Comment: @SangchulLee see the answer , the forula is not correct?

Comment: MartinArgerami's derivation is quite suggesting, but we need a little bit of correction. Notice that your formula is for the principal square root, and in MartinArgerami's answer this corresponds to the case with $-\pi < \theta < \pi$. In this regime, we have $$ z^{1/2} = r^{1/2} (\cos(\theta/2) + i\sin(\theta/2)) = r^{1/2} \left( \sqrt{\frac{1+\cos\theta}{2}} + i\operatorname{sign}(\sin(\theta/2)) \sqrt{\frac{1-\cos\theta}{2}} \right). $$ Notice the choice of sign for imaginary part. Then all the remaining computations follow in the way MartinArgerami did.

Comment: i don't understand the equation is right or not ?

Comment: @SangchulLee are you there please

Comment: @SangchulLee: you also need a $\pm$. Note that the formula your wrote always has positive real part.

Comment: The equation I presented above is correct. I am pretty sure you will agree on this as long as you follow MartinArgerami's idea.

Comment: @MartinArgerami, I am focusing only on the principal square root, as in OP's reference. Of course, the other branch of the square root will have the opposite sign.

Comment: ~@SangchulLee it is not the same result with martin Argerami

Answer (score 0):

If $z=x+iy=r\,e^{i\theta} $, then
\begin{align}
z^{1/2}&=\pm\,r^{1/2}\,e^{i\theta/2}=\pm\,r^{1/2}(\cos\frac\theta2+i\sin\frac\theta2).
\end{align}
Assuming $0\leq\pi<2\pi$, we always have $\sin\frac\theta2\geq0$. If we consider first the case where $\cos\frac\theta2\geq0$,
\begin{align}
r^{1/2}(\cos\frac\theta2+i\sin\frac\theta2)&=\pm\,r^{1/2}(\sqrt {\frac{1+\cos\theta}{2}}+i \sqrt {\frac{1-\cos\theta}{2}})\\ \ \\
&=\pm\,\left(\sqrt {\frac{r+r\cos\theta}{2}}+i\sqrt {\frac{r-r\cos\theta}2}\right)\\ \ \\
&=\pm\,\left[\left(\frac{r+x}2\right)^{1/2}+i \left(\frac{r-x}2\right)^{1/2}\right]
\end{align}

When $\cos\frac\theta2<0$, we will need a minus sign in front of the first square root, so
$$
r^{1/2}(\cos\frac\theta2+i\sin\frac\theta2)=\pm\,\left[-\left(\frac{r+x}2\right)^{1/2}+i \left(\frac{r-x}2\right)^{1/2}\right]
$$

The $\pm$ sign accounts for the existence of two square roots. In general the formula you postulate in your question cannot be right because it always has nonnegative real part (say, it would never produce $-1$ as a root of $1$).

Comment: what is the correct formula please

Comment: The one after the last equal sign in my answer. Any nonzero complex has two square roots, and each is minus the other. For instance, for $z=1$, both the + and the - formulas in your question give 1. If $z=i$, then $r=y=1$, $x=0$, and your formula gives $$\frac{1\pm i}2.$$ If you square, you'll see that the first one squares to $i$, but the second one squares to $-i$.

Comment: Typo in the comment: the 2 in the denominator should have been $\sqrt2$.

Comment: $z^{\frac12}=[\frac12(r+x)]^{\frac12}+ i[\frac12(r-x)]^{\frac12}$

Comment: That always gives one square root, the one with nonnegative real part.

Comment: i still don't understand the right equation

Comment: is it $\pm\,\left[\left(\frac{r+x}2\right)^{1/2}+i \left(\frac{r-x}2\right)^{1/2}\right]
$

Comment: That's what I wrote in my answer. But you are right, it is a little more subtle than that. Please give me a few minutes.

Comment: What do you think ?

Comment: Please see the edit.

Comment: Please why we have $\pm$ here $r^{1/2}(\cos\frac\theta2+i\sin\frac\theta2)=\pm\,r^{1/2}(\sqrt {\frac{1+\cos\theta}{2}}+i \sqrt {\frac{1-\cos\theta}{2}})$ and plese what is the exact relation in general